# Authorization Header Missing Upon NGINX Proxy Pass to subdomain

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass, laravel, nginx-reverse-proxy

Hi I'm running Laravel on NGINX server and I would like to use NGINX reverse proxy capability as an API gateway for my Laravel and other node API application. Here are my configurations:

Application URL: `staging-app.example.com`
Application API Endpoint: `staging-app.example.com/api`
API Gateway URL: `api.example.com`

What I want to do, is to redirect all API requests `api.example.com/staging-app` to `staging-app.example.com/api`. I have succeed in redirecting the API request, but somehow the `Authorization header` is not passed along to the proxy pass resulting in 401 unauthorized while other header do get passed along.

Here is my current `api.example.com` nginx config:

```
server {
        server_name api.example.com;


        location /staging-app {
                rewrite ^/staging-app/(.*)$ /$1 break; 
                proxy_pass http://staging-app.example.com/;
        }

        location /test {
                rewrite ^/test/(.*)$ /$1 break;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3333/;
         }

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = api.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name api.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

and for my laravel application, I use the configuration given from [Laravel themselves](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/deployment#nginx)

Update 1: I tried adding `proxy_set_header Test testingvalue` in the location block directly, but it doesn't seems to work either

Comment: Nothing should prevent nginx to pass the `Authorization` header to your upstream. However you are not passing your request to the `/api` endpoint; to do it, use `location /staging-app { proxy_pass http://staging-app.example.com/api; }` instead. Actually, no rewrite rules are required for your configuration to strip the URI prefix at all; check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53649885/a-little-confused-about-trailing-slash-behavior-in-nginx) SO thread to find out why.

Comment: I have installed [telescope](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/telescope) which allows me to see incoming requests. The request arrive successfully with the correct endpoint, but it's missing `Authorization header`. When I try adding another header such as `authorizationzz` it get passed through.

Comment: To check what exactly appears at the backend, I'm using a debug script with the content like [following one](https://gist.github.com/ivanshatsky/7980be97979fb2bdd8ef3b605543827e); it shows the `Authorization` header is passing correctly, so I think it is a Laravel who is in charge of it's disappearing.

Comment: @IvanShatsky I have tried running a node.js server and assign it a subdomain, when I proxy_pass to the IP (127.0.0.1:3333) the header went through, but when I use the subdomain, it disappear.

Comment: An `Authorization` header can be lost if you are 1) requesting auth and passing the `Authorization` header using different protocols (HTTP/HTTPS); 2) receiving a redirect (see related [so] threads: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28564961/authorization-header-is-lost-on-redirect), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914076/can-a-http-redirect-instruct-the-client-to-strip-a-specific-header-from-the-requ)); 3) dealing with the CORS `OPTIONS` request (see related [so] [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72279922/authorization-header-in-nginx-subrequest-is-missed)).

Comment: What you have in your config right now is not a redirection but a reverse proxying. As already being said, I don't understand how your `/staging-app` request can be passed as `/api` (however the `/staging-app/api` request will be passed as an `/api`). Did you check your actual `api.example.com` with `curl`? Can't it be a some kind of redirection?

Comment: Hi, Now i have same situation. Did you solve it?

Comment: @MilanKocic nope, in the end I just migrate all my services to use docker and use it's bridge network instead

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your config for the server listetning on port 443 :

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header   "Connection" "";
```

This will make the conection from master and agents presistent which is needed for authenticaiont in some setups

[config doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_http_version)

[nginx keep-alive doc](https://www.nginx.com/blog/avoiding-top-10-nginx-configuration-mistakes/#no-keepalives)

Comment: Nope the Authorization header still won't get through. I tried adding the `proxy_set_header Test testingvalue` in the location block directly, but somehow the value isn't added to the request.

Comment: Not passing headers is really weird. It probably requiire further investigation. Try adding the first four configs from link: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/#proxy-conf

Comment: Still doesn't work @ofirule

Comment: It probably requiire further investigation. I would recomand using `tcpdump` and/or `wireshark` for investigating the traffic

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43821612/authorization-header-in-nginx-for-proxying-to-basic-auth-backend-doest-work)?

Add to location block this entries

```
proxy_set_header  Authorization $http_authorization;
proxy_pass_header Authorization;
```

Comment: Nope still didn't work, I even manually set $http_authorization with hardcoded token. Still didn't went through. I have tried running a node.js server and assign it a subdomain, when I proxy_pass to the IP (127.0.0.1:3333) the header went through, but when I use the subdomain, it disappear.